# What part of speech is "so much so that"?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, parentheticals

> I was fascinated by the company, so much so that I wrote a book about
> it.

I am trying to understand what justifies the use of the comma before "so much so that."

Does it behave as a coordinating conjunction and therefore necessitate the comma to separate two independent clauses?

Or does it serve as the introduction to a parenthetical phrase, therefore requiring the comma?

Comment: A pause in the sentence is necessary here. The sense is "I was fascinated by the company.  In fact,  I was _so_ fascinated that I wrote a book about it."

Comment: I'd take "so much so" as a compound preposition with the clause "that I wrote a book about it" as its complement. The whole of "so much so that I wrote a book about it" is then a preposition phrase functioning as an adjunct in clause structure.

Comment: If you listen to the sentence, you'll hear the intonation change at the comma break. Commas are not "necessitated" by particular word types or clause types; they are in the speech and should be recorded when they are present in speech. If you can't hear the comma, don't write it; if you see one, listen for it.

Answer (score 1):

**so much so** (that)= to such an extent that, to such a great degree

I was fascinated by the company, so much so that I wrote a book about it.= I was **so** fascinated by the company **that** I wrote a book about it.

'I was absolutely fascinated by the company. So I wrote a book about it.' Let's join the two sentences. ➜ 'I was fascinated by the company, **so much so** (to such a great degree) that I wrote a book about it.'

There are two clauses in the sentence. We put a comma after the first clause.

'So' is an adverb. '**So much so**' is an adverbial phrase. It modifies the adjective 'fascinated'

Comment: Yes, but the OP asked about the POS of "so much so".

Comment: 'So much so' is an adverbial phrase. It modifies the adjective 'fascinated'.                                  Thank you for your contribution to my comment.

Comment: But adverbs don't take clausal complements.

Answer (score 0):

**So much so** is an adverbial phrase modifying "fascinating".

**So much** (= to a great degree) **so** (= in that manner)

Comment: But adverbs don't take clausal complements.

Comment: He held it {tightly [so ] that it did not fall.}

Comment: Nice try, Gb, but "(so) that it did not fall" is not a complement of "tightly", but a PP functioning as a purpose adjunct in clause structure, i.e. it's a modifier in the VP.